# Visualize MbTiles database

Tags: qgis, tiles, tilemill, mbtiles, offline

Imagine having a `MbTiles database` like the one you can download [here](https://www.mapbox.com/help/define-mbtiles/)
Is there a way to quickly visualize the tiles on a map? Such as an online tool, QGIS PlugIn, ...

If I get a completly unknown database, not knowing whats in there, its hardly possible to investigate the tiles, unless there is a tool that zooms automatically to the area covered by the tiles.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to view MBTiles files there are several options:
https://www.maptiler.com/how-to/mbtiles-viewer/

And this very basic one that I use:
https://viswaug.wordpress.com/2011/06/28/mbtilesviewer/

Answer (score -1):

- a - use any sqlitemanager software to look into your database.

  b - use a mbtile hosting software such as: tilestream, tilestache or mbtile-server for hosting as localhost.